# Evaluating $\int_{-1}^2 {\lfloor x\rfloor}^{x-\lfloor x\rfloor}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$$I=\int_{-1}^{2} {\lfloor{x} \rfloor{}}^{x-\lfloor{x} \rfloor{}}dx=\int_{-1}^{0} {(-1)}^{x+1} +0+1$$
So, I=$-\int_{-1}^{0}  {\exp}^{\iota\pi{x}}dx +1=\frac{{2\iota}+{\pi}}{\pi}$
Is my answer is true ?
Can someone suggest me another method for doing this integral ?

Comment: Your answer is correct

Comment: I would be very careful around the 0. IMO the integral must be split into 4 based on the interval: $I_1 = [-1, \epsilon]$, $I_2 = (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$,  $I_3 = [\epsilon, 1]$ and $I_4 (1,2]$. The $I_1$  and $I_3$ are 0, $I_4=1$, but $I_2$ needs careful treatment.

Comment: @Veliko can you elaborate  your context ?

Comment: What I mean is we need to make sure we do not have a $0^0$ limit when we are close to 0. I guess it suffices to say that in $I_2$ the function is "a true 0" to the power of $x$. You should be fine. There is a small typo in my upper comment: $I1 = [-1, -\epsilon]$.